# SlideInEffect not working on WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, slide, silverlight-toolkit

Thanks in advance for your help.  I am trying to use the toolkit slide animation on some text blocks within a PanoramaItem.  I believe all that is required is to add the toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex to each textblock that I want to slide.  Well, did that, and cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Many thanks

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="payslips" Foreground="Black">
            <ListBox x:Name="PayslipsListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllUserPayslips, Mode=OneWay}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <StackPanel Width="400">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" Foreground="Black" toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Uploaded, Converter={StaticResource UploadedLongConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" Foreground="Gray" toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex="2"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the StackPanel <StackPanel Width="400"> ?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work inside a generated ListBoxItem, however you can use it on your listbox items as far as they're already populated by the time the swipe transition happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking  `toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex` does not work inside panorama control. 
Try pivot control instead.